Blazor Update property in list, not reflected in UI
I have a list of simple properties, and I am trying to reflect the change of one of the properties in the list in the UI.
I removed this question as I got this to work in a Blazor fiddle, but Im still not able to do it in my regular code.    My code I am using,  I have an  AppStateService that has a list of items and a Complete() method that will look at the Items and set the one I specify to be complete.
In another Service, call it MyService,  I inject the AppStateService, and in a method in MyService I make a call to Complete() from the AppStateService.   It does show it changing the Item's IsComplete property, but it isnt reflected in the UI.   Ive tried using a StateHasChanged(),  EventCallBack,  Action event etc.
Here is a watered down version.
public class Foo {
    public string Title {get;set;} = "";
    public bool IsComplete {get;set;}
}

List<Foo> list = new() {
   new() { Title = "Title 1"},
   new() { Title = "Title 2"}
};

EventCallback OnComplete { get; set; }

void Complete(){
     list[0].IsComplete = true;
     StateHasChanged(); //trying this
     OnComplete.InvokeAsync(); //and this.
}


In the UI
@foreach(Foo item in list){
    <div>@item.IsComplete - @item.Title</div>
}

<button type="button" @onClick="Complete">Complete Me</button>


Ive tried EventCallBacks and just calling StateHasChanged(),  but neither one reflects the change in the list.
Any help is appreciated.  Im missing something I feel is a simple thing.  Of course it works in my fiddle, so there is something else that my app is doing that this isn't.

Try this.InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);

Looks like my issue wasn't with the state.  It was working fine.   It was an issue with another component  not reflecting my changes.  Fixed my component and all is well.
